# How to write reusable methods in cucumber + Protractor

Tags: protractor, cucumberjs

```
/* jshint -W117 */
'use strict';

var Support = require('./_support');
var $ = new Support();
var LoginPage = require('./login.page');


/**
 * Collection of basic steps definitions reusable across features
 */
var basicSteps = function (page) {
    //var page = new LoginPage();
    this.Then(/^the title should equal "([^"]*)"$/, function (arg1, callback) {
        $.expect(browser.getTitle()).to.eventually.equal(arg1).and.notify(callback);
    });

    this.Then(/^I should see validation message "([^"]*)"$/, function (arg1, callback) {
        $.expect(LoginPage.hasErrors()).to.eventually.equal(arg1).and.notify(callback);
    });

    this.Then(/^the "([^"]*)" button should be disabled$/, function (arg1, callback) {
        $.expect(LoginPage.buttonDisabled.isEnabled()).to.eventually.to.equal(false).and.notify(callback);;

    });

};

module.exports = basicSteps;
```

I want to use this code to all page files to make reusable.
I have other login.page file so if I create any other page file as per the feature I should be able to reuse this code